# Pyspark: Add the average as a new column to DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am computing mean of a column in data-frame but it resulted in all the values zeros. Can someone help me in why this is happening? Following is the code and table before and after the transformation of a column.

## Before computing mean and adding "mean" column

```
result.select("dis_price_released").show(10)
 +------------------+
 |dis_price_released|
 +------------------+
 |               0.0|
 |               4.0|
 |               4.0|
 |               4.0|
 |               1.0|
 |               4.0|
 |               4.0|
 |               0.0|
 |               4.0|
 |               0.0|
 +------------------+
```

## After computing mean and adding mean column

```
w = Window().partitionBy("dis_price_released").rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
df2 = result.withColumn("mean", avg("dis_price_released").over(w))
df2.select("dis_price_released", "mean").show(10)

+------------------+----+
|dis_price_released|mean|
+------------------+----+
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
|               0.0| 0.0|
+------------------+----+
```

Comment: whats `-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize`, are you computing a rolling mean?

Comment: also, why are you partitioning your data by the same value you want to compute the avg of?

Comment: @mtoto Question to your first question is to select all the rows. And to your above question, to select the particular "dis_price_released" column. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the `avg` first for the whole column, then use `lit()` to add it as a variable to your `DataFrame`, there is no need for window functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

mean = df.groupBy().avg("dis_price_released").take(1)[0][0]
df.withColumn("test", lit(mean)).show()
 +------------------+----+
|dis_price_released|test|
+------------------+----+
|               0.0| 2.5|
|               4.0| 2.5|
|               4.0| 2.5|
|               4.0| 2.5|
|               1.0| 2.5|
|               4.0| 2.5|
|               4.0| 2.5|
|               0.0| 2.5|
|               4.0| 2.5|
|               0.0| 2.5|
+------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you. But could you explain what does **take(1)[0][0]** do?

Comment: it extracts the actual number from the `Row` object inside the list that results from `take(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another way to solve the problem

```
df.withColumn("mean", lit(df.select(avg("dis_price_released").as("temp")).first().getAs("temp"))).show
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if you have a column you wish to calculate an average for across all rows, you should not partition by any column at all. Neither do you need to set rowsBetween in this case. Thus (assuming correct imports and the existence of the results DataFrame) your code should read:

```
w = Window().partitionBy()
df2 = result.withColumn("mean", avg("dis_price_released").over(w))
df2.select("dis_price_released", "mean").show(10)
```