# How to calculate a mean inside a window where the range of the window depends on the value of a column?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following data:

```py
columns = ['aircraft_id',      'Liftoff',    'timestamp',      'value']

l =[
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000467000,  -80.15625),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000467500,  -80.15625),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000468000,  -80.15625),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000468500,  -80.15625),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000469000,-79.8046875),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000469500,-79.8046875),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000470000,-79.8046875),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000470500,-79.8046875),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000471000,-79.8046875),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000471500,-79.8046875),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000472000,  -80.15625),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000472500,-80.5078125),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000473000, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000473500, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000474000, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000474500, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000475000, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000475500, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000476000, -80.859375),
(   '0003177d',1550000476500,1550000476500,-80.5078125)]

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

df.show()
```

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|aircraft_id|      Liftoff|    timestamp|      value|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000467000|  -80.15625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000467500|  -80.15625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000468000|  -80.15625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000468500|  -80.15625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000469000|-79.8046875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000469500|-79.8046875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000470000|-79.8046875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000470500|-79.8046875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000471000|-79.8046875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000471500|-79.8046875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000472000|  -80.15625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000472500|-80.5078125|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000473000| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000473500| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000474000| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000474500| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000475000| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000475500| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000476000| -80.859375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000476500|-80.5078125|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to calculate the mean of the value inside a window where the range between of the window depends on the current value of the timestamp to the timestamp of the Liftoff. Each aircraft has different values of Liftoff.

I try:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
df = df.withColumn('val', F.mean('value').over(Window.partitionBy('aircraft_id','ini_TO','Liftoff').orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(df['timestamp'], df['Liftoff']))
```

But it doesn't work, is there a solution?

Expected result:

- For the first row the range of the window is from 1550000467000 to 1550000476500, so the mean is the sum of the 20 values and divided by 20 (-80,33203).
- For the second row the range of the window is from 1550000467500 to 1550000476500, so the mean is the sum of the 19 values and divided by 19 (-80,34128|).
- Etc...

```py
+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+
|aircraft_id|      Liftoff|    timestamp|    value|      val|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000467000|-80,15625|-80,33203|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000467500|-80,15625|-80,34128|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000468000|-80,15625|-80,35156|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000468500|-80,15625|-80,36305|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000469000|-79,80469|-80,37598|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000469500|-79,80469|-80,41406|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000470000|-79,80469|-80,45759|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000470500|-79,80469|-80,50781|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000471000|-79,80469|-80,56641|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000471500|-79,80469|-80,63565|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000472000|-80,15625|-80,71875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000472500|-80,50781|-80,78125|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000473000|-80,85938|-80,81543|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000473500|-80,85938|-80,80915|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000474000|-80,85938|-80,80078|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000474500|-80,85938|-80,78906|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000475000|-80,85938|-80,77148|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000475500|-80,85938|-80,74219|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000476000|-80,85938|-80,68359|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000476500|-80,50781|-80,50781|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Here is the reference link to calculate mean values for a *pyspark* data frames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995188/how-to-calculate-mean-and-standard-deviation-given-a-pyspark-dataframe . You can also check this link for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382822/pyspark-add-the-average-as-a-new-column-to-dataframe

Comment: [rangebetween](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween) takes two integer values to refer to rows relative of the current row. It can't handle columns. Can you please show us the expected output of your example?

Comment: @cronoik, I edit the post with the expected result, also I edit the values of the Liftoff to make more easy the example. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there, you just need to set `rangeBetween` in window spec to start from current row `Window.currentRow` and go till end of the window range `Window.unboundedFollowing` like below:

Note : `ini_TO` is not provided in sample dataset so removed from `partitionBy` for testing.

```
wind_spec = Window.partitionBy('aircraft_id','Liftoff').orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

Above window will give desired output :

```
df.withColumn('val', F.mean('value').over(wind_spec)).show()
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+
|aircraft_id|      Liftoff|    timestamp|      value|               val|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000467000|  -80.15625|      -80.33203125|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000467500|  -80.15625|-80.34128289473684|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000468000|  -80.15625|       -80.3515625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000468500|  -80.15625|-80.36305147058823|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000469000|-79.8046875|    -80.3759765625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000469500|-79.8046875|       -80.4140625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000470000|-79.8046875|-80.45758928571429|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000470500|-79.8046875|       -80.5078125|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000471000|-79.8046875|      -80.56640625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000471500|-79.8046875| -80.6356534090909|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000472000|  -80.15625|         -80.71875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000472500|-80.5078125|         -80.78125|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000473000| -80.859375|    -80.8154296875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000473500| -80.859375|-80.80915178571429|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000474000| -80.859375|      -80.80078125|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000474500| -80.859375|       -80.7890625|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000475000| -80.859375|     -80.771484375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000475500| -80.859375|       -80.7421875|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000476000| -80.859375|      -80.68359375|
|   0003177d|1550000476500|1550000476500|-80.5078125|       -80.5078125|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```